# How to accept PUT and DELETE methods in my Rails RESTful web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've built a Ruby On Rails 3.0.x app that returns JSON. So far, I've got only four methods in my Advertisements controller: index, show, update, destroy.

When I try to call a method from an app within the same domain (through AJAX & jQuery), I succeed. But when I try to do the same from another app within another domain, I get the following error message, only when I try to use the methods PUT and DELETE (it works fine for GET and POST):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL_HERE Origin URL_HERE is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

My RESTful service is called via HTTP, not HTTPS.

Below is the AJAX code that I'm using (16 is the advertisement's id):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "http://SERVICE_URL/advertisements/16.json",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response){
            alert("test");

    }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors). We enable CORS for [our web service](http://impact.brighterplanet.com) with:

```
# config/application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do |requests|
  requests.allow do |allow|
    allow.origins '*'
    # perhaps you would stick :put and :delete here?
    # then you should follow the rack-cors documentation to only enable it where necessary
    allow.resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow man, I've been looking for this solution for a couple of days, and nothing helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @Seamus Abshere Hi I want to know why those verbs(PUT & DELETE) are protected by default. Also want to know why the Post and get methods are allowed ?